# Editar tabela no Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular-6

Tenho tido alguns problemas, por não conhecer bem o Angular 6. Tenho essa table:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let operator of dataSource">
                        <td>{{ operator.operatorId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ operator.name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Atualizar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Deletar</button> 
        </div>
</div>
```

Preciso editá-la, para poder dar um Update(Put ou Patch). Como faço? Gostaria de não usar jquery, pois estou dentro do Angular.

Comment: olá Marcelo, você precisa editar de qual forma? campos? estrutura html? pelo o que entendi você precisa de ajuda para criar a  função Update em angular, pode dar mais informações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, você pode fazer o seguinte, como você tem o ngFor, coloca uma terceira e quarta coluna para usar o operator escolhido, dessa forma:

```
<tr *ngFor="let operator of dataSource">
  <td>{{ operator.operatorId }}</td>
  <td>{{ operator.name }}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="atualizar(operator)">Atualizar</button></td>
  <td><button ng-click="deletar(operator)">Deletar</button></td>
</tr>
```

Na coluna respectiva vc informa o método do typescript que você vai chamar para fazer sua atualização ou delete, no método terá sua requisição http chamando o put ou o delete. E como os botões estão dentro do seu ng-for, você passa o operator escolhido da tabela.

Comment: A questão estava na Edição da tabela, pois o usuário quer que seja feita na própria tabela/grid a edição e exclusão. No lugar do texto, há como colocar duas imagens, tipo um "X" e um "Lápis"? Mas entendi o que você postou.

Comment: Tem sim, eu uso uma biblioteca de icones desse site: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/  é só incluir o css dele, no site tem o GetStarted no menu, lá ensina a colocar um link com a referência de css deles, tem como você baixar o css dos ícones. Após importado no seu html no lugar do texto você vai usar o icone correspondente do X ou lápis. Ex: <button><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

Comment: Gabriela, apenas uma pergunta: Criei um folder no App, chamado **images** e coloquei lá dois arquivos .png. Um se chama ***pencil*** e outro ***delete***. Como eu coloco-os no html no lugar dos botões.

Comment: Se você está usando uma <img> é só você englobar ela por um <a (click)="teste"/><sua tag img com seu arquivo .png></a>. Dessa forma o click do button ficará no link, que por sua vez referencia uma imagem dentro dele.